# Disable JSON parsing in Axios

Tags: javascript, json, axios

I have a react application in which I want the user to be able to upload code files that he can then view.

So naturally, .json files are also accepted. Now to get the file contents, I use *axios* to make a get request to the file on the server.

This works fine for everything except JSON files, which are automatically parsed and therefore not available as a String, but as a javascript object. Turning them into a string again with `JSON.stringify` removes all line breaks, so I can't do that.

Is there any way to stop Axios from automatically parsing JSON?

Comment: have you set `responseType` to `text`(default is `json`)?

Comment: @VedranJukic I've tried that already, but no change. I suppose it's because of the content-type set by the server, but I'd like to solve this on the client instead of changing my api

Comment: Thanks @VedranJukic - that was the missing piece for me.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

LuleBes answer didnt work for me. What did work was:
`transformResponse: (res) => { return res; },`
As in:

```
    axios.get(url, {
        headers,
        transformResponse: (res) => {
            // Do your own parsing here if needed ie JSON.parse(res);
            return res;
        },
        responseType: 'json'
    }).then(response => {
        // response.data is an unparsed string
    });
```

Comment: How does it help that response.data is an empty object? I want the file contents, not an empty object. I don't understand what you're doing here, seeing that your transform function takes the data and returns only an empty string.

Comment: ops, forgot to change it from my testing in my app. Now the answer should reflect the question.

Comment: didn't work for me: I had to comment //responseType: 'json', then I'd get text in res, otherwise already json.

Comment: This worked for me. Shorthand is: `transformResponse: res => res`

Answer (score 6):

Set the following option to force axios not to parse the response:

```
transformResponse: x => x
```

Usage:

```js
let response = await axios.get('/static/data.json', {
    transformResponse: x => x
});
```

Now `response.data` is a `string` as previously it was an `object`

Answer (score 4):

I've been setting a response interceptor that disables json parsing

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
      if (req.transitional) {
        req.transitional.silentJSONParsing = false;
        req.transitional.forcedJSONParsing = false;
      }
      return req;
})
```

you can also specify this per-request as per the docs https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

```js
  // transitional options for backward compatibility that may be removed in the newer versions
  transitional: {
    // silent JSON parsing mode
    // `true`  - ignore JSON parsing errors and set response.data to null if parsing failed (old behaviour)
    // `false` - throw SyntaxError if JSON parsing failed (Note: responseType must be set to 'json')
    silentJSONParsing: true, // default value for the current Axios version

    // try to parse the response string as JSON even if `responseType` is not 'json'
    forcedJSONParsing: true,
    
    // throw ETIMEDOUT error instead of generic ECONNABORTED on request timeouts
    clarifyTimeoutError: false,
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured out how that would work. You can disable response processing by just passing the `transformResponse` Array in the config, which is then used instead of the the default. There you just provide an empty array or an array of functions you need to apply to your response, like this:

```
axios.get(URL, {transformResponse: []})
.then(response => {/*response.data is plain text*/});
```

Answer (score 2):

For my case of Server Side Rendering (SSR) need to explicitly setup

> responseType

parameter which is, according to [axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#axios-api), 'json' by default

```
return axios.get(url, {
    transformResponse: res => res,
    responseType: 'text'
})
```

Without this 'responseType' parameter I was confused when [the marked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45548588/6045233) worked in tests and failed in the browser.