# Axios is parsing string response into a number

Tags: javascript, axios

I've a simple axios set up. An axios instance is created:

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: window.ENV.API_BASE,
});
```

and then I've created a `get` function using:

```
export const get = <Response = any>(url: string, config: AxiosRequestConfig<void> = {}) =>
  axiosInstance.get<Response>(url, config);
```

This function is then used to get a string from our api which is simply `'2.0'`. Reading this using `response.data` returns `2` as a number.

Why is the parsing from a number to a string happening. I can't see any options to prevent it.

Comment: Perhaps it is interpreting `2.0` as JSON and parsing it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41013082/disable-json-parsing-in-axios